# Copy Profile to a different Account Name

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles, migration

Is it possible to copy an account profile to a new account that has a different account name?

If so, I would love some links to resources on how to do this or a quick run through here, if someone would mind helping. I'm finding that I don't know the first place to start when trying this. I can clone a profile and I can migrate a profile to a new machine, but I am specifically looking to transfer all of the settings for a profile to a new profile to a new, differently named account.

Comment: Are there specific settings you wish to migrate? What is the end goal? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to setup a new account on the same machine with the exact same configuration so that two users will have everything the same, and I don't have to set it up again on the same machine.

Comment: You need to research configuring the Default user profile. That is the correct way to do this and allows the generation of unique user accounts with customized content and settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CopyProfile setting to customize a user profile and then copy that profile to the default user profile. Windows uses the default user profile as a template to assign a profile to each new user. By customizing the default user profile, you can configure settings for all user accounts that are created on the computer. By using CopyProfile, you can customize installed applications, drivers, desktop backgrounds, internet explorer settings, and other configurations.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/customize-the-default-user-profile-by-using-copyprofile

Note
Windows 10: Using CopyProfile for the “Start Menu” has been deprecated.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2018/03/12/windows-10-using-copyprofile-for-the-start-menu-has-been-deprecated/